# Facebook ID retreival by PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm trying to make a web application with Facebook using PHP SDK
I had not any problems installing and running the PHP SDK
This is my login script index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$app_id = '***************';
$app_secret = '******************************'; 
$my_url = 'https://www.domain.net/';
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(['app_id'=>$app_id,'app_secret'=>$app_secret,'default_graph_version'=>'v2.5',]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
try {
  $fbresponse = $fb->get('/me');
  $fbuserNode = $fbresponse->getGraphUser();
} catch(Exception $e) {
  error_log("index.php: Exception",0);
  $permissions = ['email'/*, 'user_likes'*/];
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://www.sofiariders.net/fblog-callback.php', $permissions);
  echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
  exit;
}
?>
```

It works perfectlyq i'm getting logged in with the facebook but the problem is - the ID of my profile.
From the $fbuserNode->getId() i'm getting the id 140261546352183
And Facebook doesn't open my profile by the URL
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=140261546352183

For example by using the site findmyfbid.com i'm getting another ID for the same profile - it's 100011050158477 and with that id Facebook successfully opens the URL
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011050158477

The question is - how can I cat my normal profile ID with the PHP SDK?
And why i'm getting wrong id?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/140261546352183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That other page is doing something that is not allowed: scraping. It gets your "real" ID directly from your profile page. In an App, you can only get an "App Scoped ID" - which is good enough to identify the user. You can just use the following URL: https://www.facebook.com/140261546352183 - it redirects to your profile.

In other words: You can´t get the "real" ID anymore, and you don´t need it.

Comment: Help alot! One more question - is this "App Scoped ID" identical on all platforms (web-PHP, android-java, ios-objective c)? If the user is logged in on my mobile applicationq then their ID is transported to my server's database, can my admin on my server view the profile of the user with the same "App Scoped ID"?

Comment: yes, of course it´s identical, it´s app scoped, not platform scoped ;) - in another app, you will get another app scoped id.

Comment: yes, your admin can view the profile with that id. check out the link in my answer.